# Issue with iPhone running app not sending data to database

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, firebase-realtime-database

I am currently working on a project which needs to send longitude and latitude data to and from my Firebase database.  When I run the program in the simulator it sends the data to the database just fine, but when I run the data on my phone it doesn't send it to the database.  I am using GeoFire to send this data, here is relevant code:

```
@objc func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {


    let latestLocation: AnyObject = locations[locations.count - 1]

    let geofireRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    let geoFire = GeoFire(firebaseRef: geofireRef)


    geoFire.setLocation(CLLocation(latitude: latestLocation.coordinate.latitude, longitude: latestLocation.coordinate.longitude), forKey: "WeGotItBitchez") { (error) in
        if (error != nil) {
            print("An error occured: \(error)")
        } else {
            print("Saved location successfully!")
        }
    }
```

Comment: What does the error say ?

Comment: I'm not getting an error, my phone just doesn't connect to the database, while the simulator does

Comment: So your method is not called on a phone ?

Comment: i was able to solve the problem by making a second account on the phone